# Series Arithmetic Progression: Real Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I encountered this question and am not sure how to tackle it, any help would be appreciated.

A real number s has a decimal representation s=0.121212121212... where '12' recurs infinitely. Using geometric progressions, express s as m/n in its lowest terms.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Multiply $s$ by $100$ and then subtract $s$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Donald, I got 11.99999999 - not sure if that's the correct answer

Comment: @HungryApe76 The fractions go on forever, so you actually have $99s = 12$, which is easily solved and simplified.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, so would the final answer simply be 4/33?

Comment: Look's good to me. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: Thank you so much! What a simple answer hiding under a complicated question lol! :) Thanks again guys